# How to detect the upmost black pixel

Tags: c#, winforms, image-processing, pixel

I have an application that creates an image from a text inputed by the user. In that image, I want to detect where is the beginning of the letters in the top so I can stamp my brand's logo and crop image accordingly.

This is what I tried so far, but can't get it to work...

```
Bitmap myBitmap = new Bitmap(Image.FromFile(@"C:\Users\me\Desktop\test_textimage.jpg"));

for (int j = 0; j < 2000; j++) // loops Y axis
{
    for (int i = 0; i < 3500; i++) // loops X axis
    {
        System.Drawing.Color color = myBitmap.GetPixel(i, j);
        if (color == System.Drawing.Color.Black)
        { // breakpoint here... it never hits...
        }
    }
}
```

I am 100% sure the image is black font into white background. Tested into photoshop.

Can anyone help? Thanks.

Comment: Duplicate? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11751255/how-to-find-black-pixel-locations

Comment: Take a look at `color` in the Debugger. Maybe you have a problem with the PixelFormat, which may or may not include an alpha channel. You may want to compare to  `Color.FromArgb(255,0,0,0);` instead of `Color.Black`. To add a little room you may instead want to test like this: `if (color.GetBrightness() < 0.1)`

Comment: @DavidBrabant its not exactly duplicate, since his was converting image to array of pixels... But it helped me find a solution anyways.

Comment: @TaW You were right on the money... thanks! It was the alpha channel that was messing my results. Thanks